# Events for checkbox in datagridview in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagridview in which I have three columns

1- int value in datagridviewtextbox

2- int value in datagridviewtextbox

3- checkbox

I want when i check any checkbox its (row) corresponding 1st column value should be added in global variable '`TOTAL`' (which is pre defined)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        label16.Text = 0.ToString();
        label17.Text = 0.ToString();
        label18.Text = 0.ToString();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(drow.Cells[4].Value) == true)
            {
                label16.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(label16.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(drow.Cells[1].Value)).ToString();
                label17.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(label17.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(label12.Text)).ToString();
                label18.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(label18.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(drow.Cells[2].Value)).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

it works when current row changes but i want when i click the checkbox immediately
it update label16,17,18

Comment: please try to be a bit more clear, So, that people may understand your problem is.

Comment: Hi, if you want to get help you should Always post the code you have so far. This will easier trigger the people here to help you!

Comment: show us how far you have gone..

Comment: now how can upload code

Comment: stackoverflow had provided us to edit our queries..

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your operation on Grid_CellClick or any suitable event handler your comfortable with

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    amt += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
// your code here
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the **lightning symbol** on the grid properties to get the list of all available **events** and choose the one which suits you best (in your case it would be **CellLeave** i think) and **double click** it:

[image]

Then you will get some generated **method signature**:

```
private void gridCellLeave(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
     // basically your code something more or less like:
     if(condition) // check if the checkbox was checked
     {
         // check other fields are not null and add them to the global value TOTAL
     }
}
```